# React-router Link, pass in params

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

If you have a route such as:

```
<Route path="/users/:userId" />
```

And then you export that route, and so it can be used across your app, such as:

```
export const MY_ROUTE = '/users/:userId/';

<Route path={MY_ROUTE} />
```

How do you set the param in a link dynamically? i.e. I would like to do this:

```
<Link to={MY_ROUTE} params={{userId: 1}} />
```

but params is totally ignored... and query just makes a query (?userId=) not a param... any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by set the param dynamically? The route should be matched automatically when you hit `/users/123`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Taken from [React Router official docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#link-to-onenter-and-isactive-use-location-descriptors):

> From the upgrade guide from 1.x to 2.x:
>
> `<Link to>`, onEnter, and isActive use location descriptors
>
> `<Link to>` can now take a location descriptor in addition to strings.
>   The query and state props are deprecated.
>
> // v1.0.x
>
> ```
> <Link to="/foo" query={{ the: 'query' }}/>
> ```
>
> // v2.0.0
>
> ```
> <Link to={{ pathname: '/foo', query: { the: 'query' } }}/>
> ```

Unfortunately, there's no support for passing in a `param` object, you yourself saw that.

In order to dynamically use the route you proposed, you would have to do something along the lines of:

```
<Link to={ MY_ROUTE.replace(':userId', '<someUserIdFromSomewhere>') }/>
```

Or you could further optimize by instead of exporting a string for `MY_ROUTE`, you could export a `userLink` function as such:

```
function userLink(userId) {
    return `/users/${userId}/`;
}
```

and then use that wherever you would want to use a `Link` to the route.

Below you can find supported parameters and API exposed on the `Link` component:

[Router Link API](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#to)

Comment: You can try using [url-pattern](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-pattern)  to construct your urls: `path={new UrlPattern(MY_ROUTE).stringify({ userId: 1})}`.  It is not a perfect match but for simple routes it can work

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question, but with React Router V4 you can use the [`path-to-regexp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp) package, which is also being used by React Router V4.

Example:

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {compile} from 'path-to-regexp';

const MY_ROUTE = '/users/:userId/';
const toPath = compile(MY_ROUTE);

// Now you can use toPath to generate Links dynamically
// The following will log '/users/42' to the console
console.log( toPath({ userId: 42 }) );
```

Of course you can use the `toPath` method to create proper links as well, example:

```
<Link to={toPath({ userId: 42 })}>My Link</Link>
```

Comment: or, even simpler:
`<Link to={\`users/${user.id}\`}>My Link</Link>`

Answer (score 6):

You could create a function which interpolate the `userId` param to create the route, something like this:

```
export const MY_ROUTE = (userId) => `/users/${userId}/`;

<Route path={MY_ROUTE(':userId')} />
```

And so in your component

```
<Link to={MY_ROUTE(1)} params={{userId: 1}} />
```

Try this solution here: 
https://jsbin.com/pexikoyiwa/edit?js,console

Comment: This should be accepted answer, it allows to build both path required by router and actual path in the redirects in the clearest way

Answer (score 2):

React Router v5 has a built in method to take in your url pattern and an object that maps to the params of the url called `generatePath`

https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/generatePath

```js
import { generatePath } from "react-router";

generatePath("/user/:id/:entity(posts|comments)", {
  id: 1,
  entity: "posts"
});
// Will return /user/1/posts
```

So used in your example would be

```
<Link to={generatePath(MY_ROUTE, {userId: 1})} />
```